# Is there any dedicated facebook request for permission for facebook users of mobile browsers?

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

Is there any different in getting **Request for Permission** from **Facebook Users** between `desktop browsers` users and `mobile browsers` users?

for example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream
```

When I check facebook developer documentation, I can't find info typically for getting permission from mobile browsers users.

I want to know ***whether I can still use my current OAuth authentication for mobile sites, to get tokens from mobile browsers users?***

Any information that I am missing?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Your current will work but there are dialogs which are more suitable for a mobile device, see below.

> show a dialog to a user on a mobile device, change the subdomain of the dialog URL from www to m. Facebook will default to an appropriate view based on the user agent. To override that choice, you can explicitly specify one of two mobile display modes:
>
> touch: Used on smartphone mobile devices, like iPhone and Android. Use this for tablets with small screens (i.e., under 7 inches) as well.
>
> wap: Display plain HTML (without JavaScript) on a small screen, such as a Nokia 7500.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

```
Overview

FB.ui is a generic helper method for triggering Dialogs that access the Facebook Dialog API endpoint.

These include:

    Publishing a story to the feed

    Prompting the user to add a friend

    **Prompting the user to authorize your application, or grant it permissions**

    Prompting a payment

    Prompting the user to send an application request to a friend

    Prompting the user to share a link
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

*(sorry for the sloppy answer, in a hurry)*